# How to check android resource type in the array of integers

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources

I would like to know whether it's possible to determine android resource type (like drawable, raw) in the array of resources like this:

```
public static final int[] resourcesArray = {
R.drawable.image1,
R.raw.image2,
R.drawable.image3
};
```

Comment: please leave your question as is, and provide your solution as answer. Thats the stackoverflow way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
String res = resources.getResourceTypeName(resid);
if (res.equals("drawable")){
    ....
}
```